# What aspect of loops causes VBA code to crash Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, merge

```
'MERGE TITLES

ChartLCN = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Row, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For mrgst = 0 To ChartLCN

    If ActiveCell.Offset(-1, mrgst) <> "" Then
        mrg = mrgst + 1

        Do While ActiveCell.Offset(-1, mrg) = ""

                 Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, mrgst).Row, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, mrgst).Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, mrg).Row, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, mrg).Column)).Merge
                  mrg = mrg + 1

        Loop
    End If


Next mrgst
```

Hello, new to stackoverflow and VBA and I have fairly long piece of VBA code that crashes when I add this code in. What I am trying to do with this loop is merge the empty cells between two non-empty cells  to the left non empty cell (Sorry, don't know how to say it better).

```
|_ _ _ _ _ |_ _ _ _ _|_ _   =>  |........|........|...

(.......Connected to left pipe)
```

I have used do-loops in the code and most of them work fine, and when they crashed I just used for-next loops. What can I do to make this piece work and avoid excel going white screen and crashing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well one thing I can see is that on the first line after the For loop starts, you are comparing a Range object to a string. Activecell.Offset(-1,mrgst) <> "" won't work. Activecell.Offset(-1,mrgst).Value <> "" would.

Comment: @rwisch45 - that is not a problem: the default Range property is `Value`, so you don't need to explicitly add it.

Comment: @Tim Williams - learn something new every day!

Comment: If you're `Do` loops "crash"` it's because you have not properly provided a means to `Exit` the loop, or because you have not accounted for potential errors (Excel notoriously hates working with merged cells, for *one* example), and not because of some inherent instability in `Loop`.  Please revise your question to indicate what error is raised, and what line of your code raises the error, if any :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim ChartLCN As Long, mrgst As Long, mrg As Long, col As Long
Dim c As Range, c2 As Range
Dim bDone As Boolean

    ChartLCN = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set c = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)

    Do While Not bDone

        Set c2 = c.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)
        If c2.Column > ChartLCN Then
            Set c2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(c2.Row, ChartLCN)
            bDone = True
        End If
        col = c2.Column + 1

        If c2.Column > c.Column Then ActiveSheet.Range(c, c2).Merge

        Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Row, col)
    Loop
End Sub
```